# Getting 404 after deploying to app server but not locally

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, url-mapping, tomcat8

I am building web service with Spring @RestController.  When testing it locally, everything is fine.  However, after deploy the app to a remote application server, I am getting 404 back when hitting the same endpoint.  Here's my codes:

```
@RestController
public class HelloRestController
{   
    @RequestMapping(  value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Here's my web application initializer.  Note: I don't have a web.xml file.

```
public class MyApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup( ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx =
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        servletContext.addListener( new ContextLoaderListener( ctx ) );

        ctx.register( WebApplicationConfig.class, ApplicationConfig.class );

        ctx.setServletContext( servletContext );

        Dynamic dispatcher =
            servletContext.addServlet( "SpringServlet", new DispatcherServlet( ctx ) );

        dispatcher.addMapping( "/" );
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup( 1 );
    }
}
```

When I deploy the app locally to Tomcat-8.0.15 and hit "localhost:8080/myApp/hello", it returns "hello".  However, after deploying the app to the remote application server (also Tomcat 8), I am getting 404 back when trying hit the same endpoint.

Thanks in advance for your helps!

Comment: code looks fine, are you sure tomcat is running on the correct port and is setup properly?

Comment: yes.  I even deployed on a cloud server, HANA Cloud Platform (HCP), and still getting 404.  I was able to see the index.html page: "remote.server.host/myApp", but not "remote.server.host/myApp/hello". :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code does look good. double check if there are any environment related issues that will causes failure to spring's bean initialization--this will cause the dispatcher servlet to fail and hence can result in a 404. common issues could be database connection being refused, classpath conflicts, JVM differences between remote application server and local.

you should be able to locate some tomcat logs to find out if there is any issues in the remote server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the remote server.  But I reproduced the issue on my local by having Tomcat to run on a older version of Java. I'll work with the deployment engineer and make sure the remote app server is running on the same version of Java as my local.  Thanks Yunbugg!!!